# Running Angular app in IOS app Webview

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, angular

I have a requirement where we have to run website in iOS app Webview by keeping website source files in locally inside iOS app. Angular need server to run the application but as we are keeping files locally we can't run the server inside iOS application (assuming). Is there any way to run the Angular application inside IOS app by keeping website files locally?

App flow: (expectation)
User opens iOS application - iOS internally opens webview with index.html file

Comment: Is this question about AngularJS or Angular?

Comment: Seems like neither, more like a "how to serve web from mobile" question

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of this comparing it with if you were testing the web pages on your development PC. When testing on your dev PC, all your web references point to your local machine. What you are attempting to do is basically the same.

Assuming that you load all your resources within the index.html page, all those references will need to be pointed to local resources on your iOS. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="public/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app/a_module.js"></script>
```

Angular.js does not need a server to run, just the angular.js file. You will need to make local copies of any code that your web app references remotely, like angular.js.

By setting the correct source references for accessing all the files via your iOS repository locally, you will have your embedded app.

BUT this does assume that your angular file web pages are currently being served as static pages by the server, and the server is NOT dynamically generating or modifying them.

(What would need to be retrieved remotely, would be changing database information that is stored on your servers, for which Angular apps commonly implement REST apis to retrieve & update. These apis can still be used the same in your iOS web view app.)